# Generating a 130-page PDF with php

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I'm using DOMpdf to generate PDF files, I'm able to generate 15 pages so far, however I need to be able to generate 130 pages, I know this might consume memory, so I'm looking for a way where I can generate each 10 pages in a separate process, and make all of them write to the same file. My question is, is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried increasing execution time allowed for PHP scripts? That would allow you to create more pages.

Comment: Why do you want 130 pages? Are you making a book?

Comment: Yes I did, but the problem is a memory problem apparently.

Comment: @putvande no I'm generating a workout program for a gym web application

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323045/dompdf-memory-issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many tools that can join PDFs together. One that I have had a lot of luck with is [PDFtk Server](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). If you generate many small PDFs (e.g. `001.pdf`, `002.pdf`, `003.pdf`) you can generate a joined PDF (e.g. `final.pdf`) with something like

```
pdftk cat 001.pdf 002.pdf 003.pdf output final.pdf
```

The page ordering of `final.pdf` will respect the order of the input files.

This is a standalone Java program, not a PHP library, so you'll have to kick the tool off with something like `shell_exec` or any number of other options.

Comment: It seem to be a great solution, but I couldn't find a way to install it on Ubuntu, I'm running on Digital Ocean.

Comment: @MohamedSaid, `pdftk` is available in the universe repository for Ubuntu 13.10. You can enable this repository as outlined at http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository